# Is there a way to set the legends of matplotlib subplots out of the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Right now I have a plot with two subplots
The problem is that in each subplot I put many traces with different colors so when I put the legend, it covers up some of the points.

[image]

The plot covers a lot of the plot space, and the legend has many traces so it seems there is no space for both

Is there a way to solve this? Perhaps (but I open to other ways) putting the legend outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `bbox_to_anchor` argument in the `plt.legend()` function

This will enable you to set the position of the legend

[This is a very nice answer already on here btw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/16815358)

Comment: I have used the answer and now my legend is outside, I also used tight layout so that it does not overlaps but now my plot X size has shrinked...

Comment: If you put the legend underneath the plot, then it would not matter. Otherwise make sure that the figure is big enough, e.g.: `plt.figure(figsize = (8,10))`